# Multiple Selectors for a .load() Function? JQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, jquery-selectors, load

Is it possible to have multiple selectors adhered to a .load() function?

Here's an example I am working on (with 4 selectors):

```
$('#embed-media').load('https://LOADURL.com/ #mediasection:first',selector1,selector2,selector3,selector4);
```

It seems like it would work, but it currently is not performing the desired function. It does grab the first selector, but the rest do not activate. Can anyone help me out?

**QUESTION UPDATE (1):**

So, I may have skewed the original question, the selectors are actually functions, and I am trying to call all of them for a single .load() functon, (see example below):

```
function selector1(){
   $(this).find(".selected-content1");}


function selector2(){
   $(this).find(".selected-content2");}
```

etc, (selector 3 and 4 would follow exactly the same).

**QUESTION UPDATE (2):**

From [thiyagu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8965628/thiyagu-selvaraj)'s suggestion, I was able to condense this more, but the selectors still do not seem to be applying to the .load() function properly...

Selectors declared (globally):

```
var selector1 = $(".selected-content1");
var selector2 = $(".selected-content2");
var selector3 = $(".selected-content3");
var selector4 = $(".selected-content4");
```

Function to .load() selectors from a designated URL, (but still is not grabbing the multiple listed selectors):

```
$('#embed-media').load('https://LOADURL.com/ #mediasection:first,selector1,selector2,selector3,selector4'‌​);
```

Still contemplating a solution, at the moment...

Comment: I think you're getting confused about the `.load()` syntax. You can't pass in variables, or functions. The string in that first argument is just that, a string. It can only take selectors like `.my-class` or `#my-id`. Passing a variable into the second argument of the function will just basically break it, because it expects that second argument to be a callback function.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. I guess I'll have to find another solution then for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load multiple selectors, you should use this:

```
$("selector").load("/url #div1, #div2");
```

You can add any selector after the URL as long as there is a space between the selector and the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is how I've implemented your code, but it doesn't seem to be working the way you describe.

`$("#embed-media").load("https://LOADURL.com/ #mediasection:first,selector1,selector2,selector3,selector4");`

Also, I should have probably noted that the selectors are functions, not ids/classes.

Comment: Selectors needs to IDs or Classes, they can't be function names. Are you trying to call multiple functions??

Comment: I am trying to call multiple functions for a single .load() function... Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so and that's bit of a weird to call multiple. Would like to understand why you need to call multiple functions? Can't those functions be merged? Would be great if you can update your question with this requirements and details.

Comment: Sorry, my original question must not have been clear enough. I have just updated the question with some additional details pertaining to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

May i know why you creating function for each selector. Instead of that  you can implement like below

```
var selector1 = $('.selected-content1'); // you can declare this in Global
var selector2 = $('.selected-content2'); // you can declare this in Global
$('#embed-media').load("https://LOADURL.com selector1 , selector2", function() 
 { 

 });
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Your suggestion to declare the selectors globally seemed to help; however, I still can't seem to get this working properly... This is what I've currently implemented, but it is not grabbing the selectors from .load():
`$('#embed-media').load('https://LOADURL.com/ #mediasection:first,selector1,selector2,selector3,selector4');`

Comment: Also, just updated my question that may give you some better clarity as to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The `load()` string requires jQuery/Sizzle selectors, not variables. `selector1` is a JavaScript variable, not a jQuery selector, so it this code _won't work_. Do you ever check your answers even work?

Comment: @MattFletcher Thanks for the info. I have been checking my answers, but they've been more of contemplations that don't turn out, as you can see. I am not very affluent with jQuery/Javascript implementing, which is why I reach out to the folks on Stack Overflow every now and then to see if they'd have any advice, or additional input.

Comment: Oh of course, I was referring not to you but to the person who answered with wildly incorrect information! You're free to ask questions and I think it's a pretty good question too